# CQ 5.6 - Rich Text Editor for end users (not for authors)

Tags: aem

Is there any way to customize the TextArea field as a Rich Text editor and make it usable by end users.

I see a documentation from Adobe on "Configuring the Rich Text Editor". I think this is only for the authors who customizes the text content in pages.

My requirement is to show the same Rich UI editor for the users to type texts with formats, alignments etc.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated..
-Nith

Comment: I would go for any open source rich text editor. Just google for it, here is a list of jQuery plugins: http://jquery-plugins.net/tag/rich-text-editor

Answer (score 0):

If its needed for end user, feel free to use any opensource/paid richtext editor. Ultimately its an arrangement of html/css & js for end user.

Comment: I understand. However, is there a way to use the out of the box control as opposed to relying on external plugins?

Comment: To use OOB RTE for user facing site, you might need to expose multiple AEM clientlibs to support RTE. So from performance & security prospective it might be a risk. I still recommend to go for opensource editors (eg. CKEditor: http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: hi @MohitBansal , can we add File Explorer plugin to CKEditor in AEM ? currently CKEditor Dialog accept images from external URL's, but can we load the images from DAM ?