# How to use Rich Text Editor in AEM web page

Tags: aem

I am creating a form, and in that I need to input some text and I want to use **Rich Text editor** in it.

When that page is published, then the user must be able to enter the text using that rich text format, i.e. Bold, italics, bullet number list etc .

How can i use the AEM rich text editor in it. I know I can include any other free editor available in the market.

I like to know that how can I use the rich text editor which is used in dialog by AEM?

Comment: There is a similar question even on the first page of questions tagged with cq: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764618/cq-5-6-rich-text-editor-for-end-users-not-for-authors

Comment: that question is not giving right answer.

Comment: How you are creating the form? For which input type you want rte?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a existing richtext editor in front end side like a field in the form. For example: wysihtml5